# showModalDialog does not open PDF in IE8

Tags: javascript, pdf, internet-explorer-8

I am using window.showModalDialog for opening a Pdf file it works in every browser but not working in IE8..it gives an empty modal...
here`s my function

```
function OpenHippaAgrementStaff(HIPAAFile) {
       var mylink = "HipaaDoc/" + HIPAAFile; 
         window.showModalDialog(mylink, self, 'status:no;resizable:yes;help:no;scroll:no;width:1000;height:600');
return false;}
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try by giving full URL like below,

```
function OpenHippaAgrementStaff(HIPAAFile) {
   var mylink = "FULL_URL_HERE_WHERE_THE_PDF_IS_LOCATED/" + HIPAAFile; 
     window.showModalDialog(mylink, self, 'status:no;resizable:yes;help:no;scroll:no;width:1000;height:600');
return false;}
```

use `document.location` object to get full url

Comment: can you elaborate please i didn`t got what are you are exactly saying..are saying that i should get the url of the folder in which pdf file is located by document.location?